# Playing and Releasing audio in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I'm learning android and currently RecyclerView, so in this example I'm playing a specific raw sound file when clicking a play button and then releasing it when it's done. 
I could seriously use some pointers on what is the best practice however as I have a few issues and questions:

- I have a problem with transiting states so if I press play very quickly I'll get an *IllegalStateException*, probably from trying to release an already released player.
- I should apparently also nullify after release and do a *null* check prior but since I'm using it in a nested scope it has to be declared final and can't be nulled which is confusing, I've obviously missed something.
- setting the clickListner on an item in *onBindViewHolder* also seems significantly slower and less responsive than adding a clickListner on the entire row in the *viewHolder* class.

**What is the best practice for setting up your mediaPlayer and managing your resources correctly with RecyclerView and what am I doing wrong that would cause crashes and "slowness"?**

//ViewHolder

```
public static class myHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{


    ImageView playBtn;

    public myHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        playBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }

}
```

//onBindViewHolder / onCompletionListener

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myHolder holder, int position) {
    myClass item = itemList.get(position);
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(holder.itemView.getContext(), item.getAudioSource());

   holder.playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you "listening in" media player? If you need to react to user interaction why not add two listeners: onLongClick(), and onClick(). LongClick can start, and when user stops pressing, onClick() will be automatically called, where you can stop playing.

Comment: I'm not in any need to stop playing actually, the sound files I use are only 1-2s long. the setOnCompleteListener is so that when the file is done playing it will release all the resources, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Declare the MediaPlayer Globally or Activity or in Adapter - pass the instance of MediaPlayer to Viewholder and try the same it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only listening in user interaction you can drop `setOnCompleteListener()` and instead define your play/stop code in (in order) `OnLongClickListener()` and `OnClickListener`. Like this:

```
holder.playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //Code to stop playing and release resources
    }
});

holder.playBtn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View v) {
           //Code to start playing 

           return false; //!!This is important so that OnClick() would be called after releasing the button
        }
    });
```

Comment: @LuckyXII Did it help?

Comment: Sorry no, it might have solved the issue that fast enough clicks would try to release an already released resource and throw an illegalStateException but only because of the longClick delay allowing the process to finish(I am howver not entirely sure that it was the cause though).
However since the audiofiles only are 1-2sec long the longClick wait is simply way too long for it to feel smooth and not a real solution to the problem.
I did find a solution I think might work but as I'm the one who came up with it and I'm absolute rookie I can't say if it's "good" practice

Comment: Well, onLongClick should execute playing the sound immediately. Thanks for the feedback anyways. Good luck!

Comment: thanks I always appreciate the help! I have posted my "solution" so that it might clarifies my issue

Answer (score 0):

OBS As I'm answering my own question I can NOT say that this is acctualy good practice but it did solve the issues I was having, if anyone spots an error or has a better more efficient way then please post an answer and elaborate.

- instead of declaring the MediaPlayer inside the onBindViewHolder I made it a class variable, this allowed me to avoid having it final and be able to nullify it after release.
- I then defined it inside the onClick method instead to make sure that it would never be null and always be declared when needed.
- I had to make my holder and "item" final in order to use them inside the onClick but this seems to have worked (recyclerView magic I guess)

The app no longer crashes and onCompletionListener should clear all resources, this is the current code:

//class variable mediaplayer and onCompletionListener method

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

//onCompletionListener method
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
};
```

//onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final itemHolder holder, int position) {
    final Items item = mItemList.get(position);

    holder.playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(holder.itemView.getContext(), item.getAudioSource());
            if(mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
            }
        }
    });
}
```