# Mediaplayer how to avoid playing multiple audios in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

i have built a list of my music (RecyclerView) in each item there are two buttons first to play the music and pause the second to stop but when i click play for two audios the two launches while i want the first one to stop. here is my adapter 
(the flag is to change th image view from play to pause when the audio is played)

```
public class ViewAudioListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAudioListAdapter.ViewHolder>{
private List<Audio> values;
private Context context;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private boolean flage = true;



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView ivPlay,ivStop;
    public View layout;


    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.textViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        this.ivPlay = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivPlay);
        this.ivStop = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivStop);

        this.layout = view;
    }
}

public void add(int position, Audio audio){
    values.add(position, audio);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void remove(int position){
    values.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public ViewAudioListAdapter(List<Audio> myDataset, Context context) {
    values = myDataset;
    this.context=context;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_audio_item, parent, false);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewAudioListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Audio audio = new Audio(values.get(position));
    final String name = audio.getName();


    holder.textViewName.setText(name);

    holder.ivPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (flage){
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context , Uri.parse(url));
                flage = false ;
            }
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                holder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.icons_play);
            }else{
                mediaPlayer.start();
                holder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.icons_pause);
            }
        }
    });

    holder.ivStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!flage){
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                flage = true;
            }
            holder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.icons_play);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return values.size();
}}
```

thank you

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040158/playing-and-releasing-audio-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

try add  `mediaPlayer.stop();` and `mediaPlayer.reset();` before start mediaPlayer use below code in click event

```
 holder.ivPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (flage){
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context , Uri.parse(url));
            flage = false ;
        }
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            holder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.icons_play);
        }else{
             mediaPlayer.stop();//add here
            mediaPlayer.reset();//update here
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context , Uri.parse(url));// new update here
            mediaPlayer.start();
            holder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.icons_pause);
        }
    }
});
```

this may help..

**OR**

```
holder.ivPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (flage){
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context , Uri.parse(url));
                flage = false ;
            }
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                holder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.icons_play);
            }else{

                 try {

                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                     mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                      mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context , Uri.parse(url));
                               }

                 mediaPlayer.start();
                holder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.icons_pause);
} catch (Exception e) {
}

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException in mediaPlayer.start

Comment: try **reset()** instead **release()** check updated code

Comment: with reset it doesn't play the music at all

Comment: with your prepositions i lose my pause functionality as you do a "mediaPlayer.create"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160602/discussion-between-omi-and-achraf).